# How to save the line number when using error_log in PHP?

Tags: php, error-logging, error-log

When using error_log(..) in PHP I would like to specify the line where the error occurred :

```
error_log("something bad happened on line $LINE");
```

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should use a [Magic constant](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.magic.php) called `__LINE__`, so:

```
error_log("something bad happened on line ".__LINE__);
```

Another useful magic constant in this context may be `__FILE__` for the filename:

```
error_log(
    sprintf(
        "%s:%d: something bad happened",
        __FILE__,
        __LINE__
    )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer this:

```
error_log(__FILE__ . ':' . __LINE__ . ' something bad happened');
```